# Adding additional IF Functions to formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(J2325<1,"1",(((J47*J48)+(J426*J427)+(J805*J806)+(J1184*J1185)+(J1563*J1564)+((IF(J1942<1,".0001",(J1942*J1943)))))))/(J2325)
```

I am having trouble adding additional IF functions as needed. I need a formula that can replicate the following portion of the function.

```
IF(J1942<1,".0001",(J1942*J1943)
```

I need to replicate this for J47, J426, J805, J1184, and J1563.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap your hard numbers in quotes. They become textual representations of numbers and while using them in a mathematical operation like addition or division is usually sufficient to get Excel to revert them to true numbers, it is wholly unnecessary and generally considered a bad practise to get into.

Here is your formula broken down with some line feeds and indentation for clarity. I've used a minimal number of bracketing pairs as well.

```
=IF(J2325<1, 1,
    (IF(J47<1, 0.0001, J47*J48)+
     IF(J426<1, 0.0001, J426*J427)+
     IF(J805<1, 0.0001, J805*J806)+
     IF(J1184<1, 0.0001, J1184*J1185)+
     IF(J1563<1, 0.0001, J1563*J1564)+
     IF(J1942<1, 0.0001, J1942*J1943))/J2325)
```

That can be used as is or the line feeds and indentation can be removed.

```
=IF(J2325<1, 1, (IF(J47<1, 0.0001, J47*J48)+IF(J426<1, 0.0001, J426*J427)+IF(J805<1, 0.0001, J805*J806)+IF(J1184<1, 0.0001, J1184*J1185)+IF(J1563<1, 0.0001, J1563*J1564)+IF(J1942<1, 0.0001, J1942*J1943))/J2325)
```